# Unexpected behavior of bound function

Tags: javascript, node.js, currying

Tried to create a function mapping numeric characters (i.e. '0' to '9') to `true` and other characters to `false`:

```
const isNumeric = String.prototype.includes.bind('0123456789');
```

`isNumeric('1')` and `isNumeric('0')` returned `true`.
Expected `['1', '0'].every(isNumeric)` to be true too but it turned out to be false.

Something I'm missing?

This was on node v10.16.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) has a second parameter called `position` which is the position within the string at which to begin searching. `every`, like every other array prototype methods, provides the index as the second argument to the callback provided. So, the code ends up being something like this:

```js
const exists = ['1', '0'].every((n, i) => isNumeric(n, i))

// Which translates to
// Look for "1" starting from index 0. It is found
// Look for "0" starting from index 1. Fails because "0" is at index 0
 const exists = ['1', '0'].every((n, i) => '0123456789'.includes(n, i))
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const isNumeric = String.prototype.includes.bind('0123456789'),
      numbers = Array.from('149563278'); // array of numbers in random order

console.log( numbers.every(isNumeric) ) // false

console.log( numbers.every(n => isNumeric(n)) ) // true
```

Comment: Good catch :) That explains it